# How to use function "summarySEwithin()" to analysis repeated measured data?

Tags: r, summary, errorbar

I have a question about plotting error bar with a repeated measured dataset.
I have the dataset like this:

```
    Food_type Quantity Temperature Time Diameter
    Food1      High       High      6    0.00100
    Food1      Medium     High      6    0.00090
    Food1      Low        High      6    0.00085
    Food2      High       High      6    0.00100
    Food2      Medium     High      6    0.00090
    Food2      Low        High      6    0.00085
    ...
```

I fed an animal larvae with different food type, different food concentration, and culture the larvae in different temperature, every 6 days, I measured their size.

I want to plot error bar of this dataset, since the data is repeated measured, I need to use function "SummarySEwithin()" to summary the data before I plot it.
and also I used the function of "SummarySE()" and "normDatawithin()", followed the method ([enter link description here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Summarizing_data/))

Here is my code:

```
    summarySEwithin(data, measurevar = "Diameter", groupvars= c("Quantity","Temperature", "Time"),idvar="quality")
```

and I also tried to add a column of "Subject" in the dataset, and write the code:

```
    summarySEwithin(Data, measurevar = "Diameter", groupvars= c("Quality","Quantity","Temperature", "Time"),idvar="Subject")
```

They are all have "unused argument" error.

Somebody can help me with my case? Any answer will be high appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: For this kind of summarizing I think you're better off with `dplyr` or `data.table`, this is what they're very good at.  But! `unused argument` nearly always means you're including an extra parameter in your function call, I would check your syntax.  Alternatively, if you use the package plotly or ggplot2, you can do box plots without summarising your data first.

Answer (score 0):

Some test data:

```
data <- data.frame(expand.grid(Quality = c('Food1','Food2'),
                           Quantity = c('High', 'Medium', 'Low'), 
                           Temperature = c('High','Low'), 
                           Time = 1:6,
                           Sample = 1:3))
data$Diameter <- runif(NROW(data))
```

dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
# I'm using standard dev as my measurement of error, but you can use
# any other definition you want
plotdata <-
 data %>% 
  group_by(Quality, Quantity, Temperature, Time) %>%
  summarise(DiameterMean = mean(Diameter),
            DiameterErr = sd(Diameter)) %>%
  arrange(Time)
```

data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
data <- setDT(data)
plotdata <- data[,.(DiameterMean = mean(Diameter),
                    DiameterErr = sd(Diameter)), 
                 by = .(Quality, Quantity, Temperature, Time)][order(Time)]
```

now plot either with plotly or ggplot2:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data = plotdata,
        y = DiameterMean, 
        x = Time, 
        error_y = list(array = DiameterErr), 
        color = paste0(Quantity,'-', Quality,'-',Temperature))
```

ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = plotdata) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Time, 
                y = DiameterMean, 
                color = paste0(Quantity,'-', Quality,'-',Temperature))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = Time,
                    ymin = DiameterMean - DiameterErr,
                    ymax = DiameterMean + DiameterErr,
                    color = paste0(Quantity,'-', Quality,'-',Temperature)))
```